# Obtain value of -webkit-text-stroke-color in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a -webkit-text-stroke-color css property that changes at scroll and I need to obtain its value to work with another function, how can i get it? I've been trying different ways and anyone works, this is what i have:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#1blur').click(function () { 
$(this).css({
'border-right':'white 1px solid',
'opacity':'1.0',
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
});
$('#2blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('#3blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('#4blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('.addblur').css({
'border-right':'none'
});
$('.position').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position').removeClass('ablur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('ablur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('ablur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('ablur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position').removeClass('bblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('bblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('bblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('bblur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position').removeClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('cblur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position').removeClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('cblur4');
})
$('#2blur').click(function () { 
$(this).css({
'border-right':'white 1px solid',
'opacity':'1.0',
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
});
$('#1blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)'
});
$('#3blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('#4blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('.addblur').css({
'border-right':'none'
});
$('.position').addClass('blur1');
$('.position2').addClass('blur1');
$('.position3').addClass('blur1');
$('.position4').addClass('blur1');
$('.position').addClass('ablur1');
$('.position2').addClass('ablur2');
$('.position3').addClass('ablur3');
$('.position4').addClass('ablur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position').removeClass('bblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('bblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('bblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('bblur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position').removeClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('cblur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position').removeClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('cblur4');
})
$('#3blur').click(function () { 
$(this).css({
'border-right':'white 1px solid',
'opacity':'1.0',
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
});
$('#1blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)'
});
$('#2blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)',
'opacity':'1.0'
});
$('#4blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
'opacity':'0.5'
});
$('.addblur').css({
'border-right':'none'
});
$('.position').addClass('blur2');
$('.position2').addClass('blur2');
$('.position3').addClass('blur2');
$('.position4').addClass('blur2');
$('.position').addClass('bblur1');
$('.position2').addClass('bblur2');
$('.position3').addClass('bblur3');
$('.position4').addClass('bblur4');
$('.position').removeClass('ablur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('ablur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('ablur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('ablur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position').removeClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('cblur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur3');
$('.position').removeClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('cblur4');
})
$('#4blur').click(function () { 
$(this).css({
'border-right':'white 1px solid',
'opacity':'1.0',
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
});
$('#1blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)'
});
$('#2blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)',
'opacity':'1.0'
});
$('#3blur').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.35)',
'opacity':'1.0'
});
$('.addblur').css({
'border-right':'none'
});
$('.position').addClass('blur3');
$('.position2').addClass('blur3');
$('.position3').addClass('blur3');
$('.position4').addClass('blur3');
$('.position').addClass('cblur1');
$('.position2').addClass('cblur2');
$('.position3').addClass('cblur3');
$('.position4').addClass('cblur4');
$('.position').removeClass('ablur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('ablur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('ablur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('ablur4');
$('.position').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur1');
$('.position').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position2').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position4').removeClass('blur2');
$('.position').removeClass('bblur1');
$('.position2').removeClass('bblur2');
$('.position3').removeClass('bblur3');
$('.position4').removeClass('bblur4');
})
});

function animateIt() {
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
 if (!enable) return;
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scroll > 0 && scroll < 1000) {
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(72,145,0,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(72,145,0,1.00)',
   })
  $('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(72,145,0,0.20)',
   })
  $('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(72,145,0,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(72,145,0,0.05)'
   })
  }
   if ( scroll > 1000 && scroll < 2000) {
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(229,200,96,1.00)'
   })
  $('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(229,200,96,1.00)',
   })
  $('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(229,200,96,0.20)',
   })
  $('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(229,200,96,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(229,200,96,0.05)'
   })
 
  }
   if ( scroll > 2000 && scroll < 3000) {
  $('.position3').css({
'color':'rgba(52,52,52,1.00)'
   })
  $('.ablur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(52,52,52,1.00)',
   })
  $('.bblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(52,52,52,0.20)',
   })
  $('.cblur3').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(52,52,52,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(52,52,52,0.05)'
   })
  }
    });
}
animateIt();
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scroll > 0 && scroll < 1000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(186,153,82,1.00)',
'background':'none'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(239,240,207,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position4').css({
'color':'rgba(235,246,177,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(186,153,82,1.0)',
   })
  $('.ablur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(239,240,207,1.0)',
   })
  $('.ablur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(235,246,177,1.0)',
   })
  $('.bblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(186,153,82,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(239,240,207,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(235,246,177,0.2)',
   })
  $('.cblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(186,153,82,0.05)',
   })
  $('.cblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(239,240,207,0.05)',
   })
  $('.cblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(235,246,177,0.05)',
   })
  }
   if ( scroll > 1000 && scroll < 2000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(193,59,21,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(68,25,16,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(246,246,248,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position4').css({
'color':'rgba(218,149,20,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(193,59,21,1.0)',
   })
  $('.ablur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(246,246,248,1.0)',
   })
  $('.ablur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(218,149,20,1.0)',
   })
  $('.bblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(193,59,21,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(246,246,248,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(218,149,20,0.2)',
   })
  $('.cblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(193,59,21,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(193,59,21,0.05)'
   })
  $('.cblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(246,246,248,0.05)','color':'rgba(246,246,248,0.05)'
   })
  $('.cblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(218,149,20,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(218,149,20,0.05)'
   })
  }
   if ( scroll > 2000 && scroll < 3000) {
  $('.position').css({
'color':'rgba(108,69,48,1.00)',
'background':'rgba(214,193,165,1.00)'
   })
  $('.position2').css({
'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
   })
  $('.position4').css({
'color':'rgba(18,124,23,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(108,69,48,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)',
   })
  $('.ablur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(18,124,23,1.0)',
   })
  $('.bblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(108,69,48,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
   })
  $('.bblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(18,124,23,0.2)',
   })
  $('.cblur1').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(108,69,48,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(193,59,21,0.05)'
   })
  $('.cblur2').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.05)','color':'rgba(246,246,248,0.05)'
   })
  $('.cblur4').css({
'-webkit-text-stroke-color':'rgba(18,124,23,0.05)',
'color':'rgba(18,124,23,0.05)'
   })
  }
 });
animateIt();
```

```css
body{background:black; height:3000px;}
.position{
background:black;
color:rgba(186,153,82,1.00);
font-weight:900; 
font-size:12px;
font-family:mono; 
margin-top:0;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:40px;

}
.position2{
color:rgba(239,240,207,1.00);
font-weight:900; 
font-size:12px;
font-family:mono; 
margin-top:0;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:40px;
}
.position3{
color:rgba(72,145,0,1.00);
font-weight:900; 
font-size:12px;
font-family:mono;  
margin-top:0;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:40px;

}
.position4{
color:rgba(235,246,177,1.00);
font-weight:900; 
font-size:12px;
font-family:mono; 
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-top:40px;

}
#layer1{width:700px; height:700px;  margin-left:50%; left:-350px; position:fixed; z-index:5; text-align:center; margin-top:10px;}
#layer2{width:700px; height:700px; margin-left:50%; left:-350px; position:fixed; z-index:10; text-align:center;margin-top:30px;}
#layer3{width:700px; height:700px; margin-left:50%; left:-350px; position:fixed; z-index:15; text-align:center;margin-top:50px;}
#layer4{width:700px; height:700px; margin-left:50%; left:-350px; position:fixed; z-index:6; text-align:center;margin-top:70px;}
#blur_bar{border: 2px white solid; position:fixed;}
.blur1{ 
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px; 
 }
.blur2{ 
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 10px; 
 }
.blur3{ 
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 25px; 
 }
 .ablur1{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(186,153,82,1.0);
}
.ablur2{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(239,240,207,1.0);
}
.ablur3{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(72,145,0,1.0);
}
.ablur4{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(235,246,177,1.0);
}
.bblur1{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(186,153,82,0.2);
}
.bblur2{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(239,240,207,0.2);
}
.bblur3{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(72,145,0,0.2);
}
.bblur4{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(235,246,177,0.2);
}
.cblur1{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(186,153,82,0.05);
color:rgba(186,153,82,0.2);
}
.cblur2{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(239,240,207,0.05);
color:rgba(239,240,207,0.05);
}
.cblur3{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(72,145,0,0.05);
color:rgba(72,145,0,0.05);
}
.cblur4{
-webkit-text-stroke-color:rgba(235,246,177,0.05);
color:rgba(235,246,177,0.05);
}
.addblur{width:28px; height:28px; display:inline-block;float:left;cursor:pointer; padding:0; font-size:10px; color:white; line-height:28px; text-align:center;border-right:white 1px solid; background:rgba(217,217,217,1.00); opacity:1; z-index:100;}
#blur_options{ width:120px; height:30px; margin-top:100px; position:fixed; left:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer1">
<pre id="ash1" class="position">
A
</pre>
  </div>
<div id="layer2">
<pre id="ash1" class="position2">
A
</pre>
  </div>
<div id="layer3">
<pre id="ash1" class="position3">
A
</pre>
  </div>
<div id="layer4">
<pre id="ash1" class="position4">
A
</pre>
  </div>
<div id="blur_options">
<h1 style="top:0; font-size:10px; font-weight:100; padding:0; line-height:8px; color:white;">Blur Gradient <br>
(just Chrome browser)</h1>
<div id="blur_bar">
<div class="addblur" id="1blur">0%</div>
<div class="addblur" id="2blur" style="opacity:0.5">33%</div>
<div class="addblur" id="3blur" style="opacity:0.5">66%</div>
<div class="addblur" id="4blur" style="opacity:0.5">99%</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('.ablur2').css("-webkit-text-stroke-color") returns the css. Provided you have an element with the class ablur2 which has the -webkit-text-stroke-color set. So I'm confused as to the question.

Comment: thanks for answering @spaceman the albur2 -webkit-text-stroke-color changes at scroll all the time but just appears when i click certain button, so I call its value before add the class to load the updated value.

Comment: Do you mean you want to obtain the value every time a scroll event occurs?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I want to get the value  displayed by the scroll event when I click on a button @spaceman

Comment: If the scroll event changes the -webkit-text-stroke-color property, using $('.ablur2').css("-webkit-text-stroke-color") will return the value when you click a button. Could you post more code? Still not sure what the problem is sorry.

Comment: sure @spaceman I'mma do a HUGE edit haha give me a minute

Comment: That seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/9nwqw0pd/ just not sure what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: When you click on any of the 33% or 66% or 99% buttons it should at 3 different classes @spaceman

Comment: @ArturoGarcía "it should at 3 different classes" <- it should what?

Comment: Oh, the 4 divs with the ids layer1, layer2, layer3 & layer4 are on top of the div where the click event's occur, blocking them from being clicked. I changed the z-index to 10 on #blur_bar and you can now click all 4. https://jsfiddle.net/9nwqw0pd/1/

Comment: thanks @spaceman but this isn't the problem I got it fixed in my file :)